# Can I remotely access a backtrack computer

Tags: vpn, remote-access, backtrack

I have a pc with the latest backtrack version. I would like to place it inside my protected network to perform some pentests and other network diagnostics. However, I would like to be able to access it through my personal computer when I am inside the VPN tunnel.

Is it possible to remote access a computer with backtrack?

Comment: Why not just hax0r you way into it? ;)

Comment: Are you looking for command line only or GUI access?

Answer (score 1):

Not only is it possible with Backtrack, it is essential to validate your assumptions on security. Consult with them for tips for pentests and setup.

As my favourite God of security, Bruce Schneirer has said for years:

> Security consists of;
>
> 1. protection,
> 2. detection,   and
> 3. response,    and
>
>    You need all three to have good security

So pentests are essential and must be repeated often to validate your assumptions. If you do it right, you WILL find lots of security violations possible. If you can afford the time to find them, you can afford the time to fix them.

Otherwise just let the others think what security issues? Who needs pentest anyways?

Comment: I don't see how this is answering the question.

Comment: @slhck - The author's question is **Is it possible to remote access a computer with backtrack?** I feel Tony actually did answer the question at hand.  Could he have gone into how to do it, I suppose, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: @Ramhound Well, I thought this was about explaining *how*? (Although the question is a yes/no one, granted)

Comment: I often get criticize for giving too much valuable information but not answering the question. The answers are readily available but perhaps too valuable to let kiddy scripters try to do some pentesting of their own on those ports. Which I could but deferred in this case to just answer the question and justify its validity of purpose with the top security guru http://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2007/05/is_penetration.html in the USA.  here's a bank robbery during a pentest http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJVHTQSvUIo

Comment: Maybe I didn't do the question correctly, but my question is:
Can I with my windows computer remote access a PC with the backtrack OS, so then I can perform the pentesting?

Comment: http://www.backtrack-linux.org/tutorials/