# Can I remote access a backtrack PC with a Windows PC

Tags: vpn, remote-access, backtrack

I have a pc "A" with the latest backtrack version. I would like to place it inside my protected network to perform some pentests and other network diagnostics. I have a PC "B" outside that network and I would like to, after closing the tunnel, remote access that PC "A" with the backtrack OS, so then I can perform the pentesting?

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you be more explicit? What tunnel? Where is your Windows PC. What is a "protected network". Then is there any diference between this questions and the one you've made [here](http://superuser.com/questions/442718/can-i-remotely-access-a-backtrack-computer)?

Comment: Yes, I will try to make it clearer! I want to remote access a "PC with backtrack" from my "windows PC"...that simple. Is it possible?

Comment: Configure vnc on the backtrack computer I believe would let you access it.

Answer (score 1):

Backtrack is linux, so you have all the options for accessing it remotely that you would with a normal linix distribution.

The most common ones are

- ssh for command line access, and you can use [putty](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) from Windows
  to get to it.
- vnc for remote access to the gui (you will need to
  start the VNC service for this to work)
- X forwarding - where you run
  an X server locally on your Windows machine with [Xming](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) for
  example, and use the -X parameter with ssh to forward gui sessions to
  your Windows pc (in putty this is in the ssh session options).